# Trying to make a movie likeable one time

Tags: javascript, local-storage, storage

I'm trying to make movies likeable one time by storing them in an array like this:

```
let likedMovies = [];
const movieLike = document.getElementById("likeButton");
likedMovies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("likedMovies"));
movieLike.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (likedMovies.indexOf(allMovies[i].name) === -1) {
    confirm("Movie liked");
    axios.patch(`url`);
    likedMovies.push(allMovies[i].name);
    localStorage.setItem("likedMovies", JSON.stringify(likedMovies));
    return true;
  }
  confirm("Movie already liked");
  return false;
});
```

it was working this afternoon but now the console display an error log saying this: "script.js:75 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'indexOf')
at HTMLDivElement." and when I log my likedMovies array, it says that arrays's "null", could you please help me understanding why it doesn't work ?

Comment: If the user opens a different browser, will the user be able to like again? I think this needs backend handling, and simply restricting in front end by not updating the 'like'

Comment: how are you setting the likedMovies on localStorage ?

Comment: It is super clear that `likedMovies` is no longer in `localStorage`.

Comment: @FaizalHussain with  localStorage.setItem("likedMovies", JSON.stringify(likedMovies))  inside the if

Comment: @WaisKamal how can I put it back in ?

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("likedMovies", "[]")`.

Comment: @Deepak i see but the problem is that I can't do backend handling because it's for school :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are reassigning `likedMovies` with the result of `JSON.parse` which is null if it's unable to parse it.

```
let likedMovies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("likedMovies")) || [];
```

This should solve the error, but also you can do some optimization by storing it as an Object.

```
let likedMovies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("likedMovies")) || {};
const movieLike = document.getElementById("likeButton");
movieLike.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (likedMovies[allMovies[i].name]) {
    confirm("Movie liked");
    axios.patch(`url`);
    likedMovies[allMovies[i].name] = true;
    localStorage.setItem("likedMovies", JSON.stringify(likedMovies));
    return true;
  }
  confirm("Movie already liked");
  return false;
});
```

Now your search will happen not in linear time which is O(n) but in constant O(1). Tiny performance improvement.